# Print menu. Exception java.util.NoSuchElementException no line found

Tags: java, exception, switch-statement, user-defined-functions

I am working on a relatively simple project what displays a menu and prompts the user to input to be used in a switch statement, all contained within a method. However the program generates an exception;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at AuthoringAssistant.printMenu(AuthoringAssistant.java:49)
at AuthoringAssistant.main(AuthoringAssistant.java:64)
```

Here is a snippet of code where i believe to be causing the issue;

```
   private static char printMenu(){
  Scanner scnr = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("\nMENU");
  System.out.println("c - Number of non-whitespace characters");
  System.out.println("w - Number of words");
  System.out.println("f - Find text");
  System.out.println("r - Replace all !'s");
  System.out.println("s - Shorten spaces");
  System.out.println("q - Quit");

  System.out.println("\nChoose an option: ");


  char choice=scnr.nextLine().charAt(0);//line 49
  return choice;
}
```

Somewhere down in main where the function is called:

```
 while(endMenu == false){
    char ch =printMenu();//line 64

     switch(ch){
```

Thanks if you can provide any feedback!

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any wrong with the scanner in the current code.  Could you provide more information about when this is occuring?

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry I do not have enough rep to comment, this should be a comment.)

When do you get the exception?  Does it wait for you to key in the input?  And what value do you key in at the prompt?

May be because you are tying to call the charAt() with nextLine() it throws the exception.  Can you try this?

```
String choiceString = scnr.nextLine();
char choice = choiceString.charAt(0);
return choice;
```

Comment: the issue arises when the ch = printMenu(); is called down in main. The program prints out the menu and prompts the user for input . When the user enters a character the exception appears.

I tried your solution Jerin Joseph, but the exception still points to the scnr.nextline(); statment and at ch = printMenu();

Comment: By the way I am using running this through the Zybooks teaching tool.

Comment: @scubasteve7  I do not see anything wrong with the code.  May be the fact that this is being run using a tool is causing the issue.  The tool is probably not reading the input stream right.

Comment: @scubasteve7 You can try scnr.next(); instead of nextLine(), just a wild try, can't understand how the zybooks tool behaves.

Comment: Thanks for the effort man i ran the program in an ide and it works just fine so i guess its just the janky zybook program... great to know i wasted most of my day due to an ineffective leanring tool that we HAVE to use...